# Generating a reference list of software packages

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Many questions here do or will ask about the capability of various software packages. We might find it helpful to generate a list of links (or even better) descriptions etc. of the most commonly used or innovative packages. Does https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tags/software/info seem like a good place to do this? If so, go forth and edit!

Comment: I'd add that the descriptions should also be on the specific tags' wikis.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think specific software packages should be listed as that would be a subjective listing and unfair to those not listed. There are over 700 programs for genealogy available. See [GenSoftReviews](http://www.gensoftreviews.com). Also it would take regular maintenance, since software programs come and go and change capability.

There are [sites that have good comparisons and reviews](http://www.gensoftreviews.com/?page_id=6), but we don't want to be linking to sites away from StackExchange.

So I'm not sure what's best here.

Note: I run GenSoftReviews.

Comment: Even linking to review sites in the wiki would give you something to hand folks looking for software. Follow it up with, "come back if you have a specific question about the use of a software package".

Comment: I'd be happy to link to review sites; it's either that or do the work ourselves. Is GenSoftReviews the only such beast, or could we give users a choice?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: All the sites that I know of that list or compare or review genealogy software are listed at http://www.gensoftreviews.com/?page_id=6 - If anyone knows of any others, I'd be happy to add them.

Comment: That's an extensive list -- almost too extensive to be useful.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - Maybe what might be better, is as people ask questions about different programs, a new tag is added for each program. That tag could then get a short description of the program. Meanwhile, the "software" tag could just be a list of the programs that have tags, and the tag will of course link to all the questions for that program.